# JQuery.when() not doing as i expect

Tags: jquery

So i have below code. It seems that when in JQuery i wan't to get the Width and Height of a photo, there is a smal delay to laod the picture (maybe because of the size of the foto 3.6MB) So i was googling around and found the JQuery.when() function. But if i run below code, it will first alert the $fotoWidth and $fotoHeight (NaN - NaN) after that the alerts trigger from the 2 functions. But that is to late as $vehoudingFoto then already has NaN as value. Some tips or advise how to solve this? If not working with $.when() then maybe some other function?

```
$.when(getOriginalWidthOfImg(image2),getOriginalHeightOfImg(image2)).then(function($fotoWidth,$fotoHeight) {
    alert($fotoWidth+" - "+$fotoHeight);
    $verhoudingFoto=$fotoWidth/$fotoHeight;
});
function getOriginalWidthOfImg(img_element) {
    var tW = new Image();
    tW.src = img_element;
    $(tW).on('load',function(){
        orgWidth = tW.width;
        alert(orgWidth);
        return orgWidth;
    });
}

function getOriginalHeightOfImg(img_element) {
    var tH = new Image();
    tH.src = img_element;
    $(tH).on('load',function(){
        orgHeight = tH.height;
        alert(orgHeight);
        return orgHeight;
    });
}
```

Comment: you need to pass a promise to the $.when() also there is no need to have 2 calls to get the height and width of an image

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for your response but how can i pass a promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I think you can use a simple callbak, there is no need for deferred...

```
getOriginalDimensionsOfImg(image2, function (width, height) {
    alert(width + " - " + height);
})

function getOriginalDimensionsOfImg(src, callback) {
    var tW = new Image();
    $(tW).on('load', function () {
        callback(tW.width, tW.height);
    });
    tW.src = src;
}
```

```js
function test(image2) {
  getOriginalDimensionsOfImg(image2, function(width, height) {
    console.log(image2, width + "X" + height);
  })
}

function getOriginalDimensionsOfImg(src, callback) {
  var tW = new Image();
  $(tW).on('load', function() {
    callback(tW.width, tW.height);
  });
  tW.src = src;
}

test('//placehold.it/32');
test('//placehold.it/64');
test('//placehold.it/32X64');
test('//placehold.it/32');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```